# Camera view of UIImagePickerController frozen when navigating back to it

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uiimagepickercontroller

In the delegate of `UIImagePickerController` when an image is taken with the camera, another view is pushed onto the navigation stack:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    picker.pushViewController(otherViewController, animated: true)
}
```

In the `otherViewController` the navigation bar is made visible:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false) 
}
```

When the `< Back` button in the navigation bar is tapped, the navigation bar becomes invisible again, the camera view appears, but the camera image is frozen and tapping the bottom bar buttons has no effect.

Why is that?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution or workaround for that ?

Comment: @vib Yes, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround is not to offer the user to navigate back by replacing the `Back` button with a `Cancel` button. That dismisses the UIImagePickerController and automatically dismisses all higher views on the navigation stack, including the `otherViewController`.

```
// Replace `Back` button with `Cancel` button in the `otherViewController`
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(self.cancelButtonTapped))

@objc func cancelButtonTapped() {

   // Dismiss the `UINavigationController`, e.g. by calling a delegate function
   // ...
}
```

As a result the user would have to start the process again from the beginning instead of just navigating back.

Answer (score 0):

You are directly pushing A new view before dismissing picker you had presented this is why when you come back your camera image picker is still on stack as its not dismissed

```
dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
```

after this push your new View as you want. didFInish is used to get the result and dismiss the picker you used pass image selected or clicked to new controller if required but dismissing to picker is required

Comment: Why would the picker have to be dismissed before pushing a new view controller onto the navigation stack? The purpose of the navigation controller is to keep VCs on the stack to be able to navigate back to previous VCs.